# yii2 select2 gridview filter searchmodel

Tags: gridview, filter, yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I'm trying to filter a yii2 gridview with a select2

In ModelSearch I have

```
 ->andFilterWhere(['like', 't_persons.functions', $this->functions ])
```

Unfortunately string (1) matches 10 and 11 as well

[image]

How can I filter the integer values from the comma separated field?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string of comma separated values, I would try:

```
->andFilterWhere('t_persons.functions in ('.$this->functions.')')
```

Answer (score 0):

To match a single value in a comma-separated field use FIND_IN_SET, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM t_persons WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', functions);
```

To integrate that into Yii2, you might (if I've understood your nomenclature correctly) use:

```
->andFilterWhere(new Expression('FIND_IN_SET(:function_to_find, functions)'))->addParams([':function_to_find' => $this->functions])->asArray()->all();
```